# Does CEXIO support withdraw and deposit via API?

Tags: blockchain, kraken.com

.Found similar methods for Kraken but can't seem to find them in CEXIO REST and WebSocket documentation

Comment: Did you ever found a way to do it? Looking for the same thing...

Comment: @JoostPielage, There is no way as of now, maybe u can checkout  cex io aggregator, its premium, but a little costly though. I am not sure it support this

Answer (score 0):

*withdrawals are restricted through API due to security reasons*. As for the deposit, you can use *Get crypto address* to get the deposit address and use it with some other exchanges API